# Why I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, camunda, cockpit

I'm trying to deploy a bundle in karaf. I want to create a process engine inside of it which connects to h2 database. I have the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.190</version>
</dependency>
```

In `ini()` method I try to create engine process using:

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration()
    .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE)
    .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:my-own-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000")
    .setJobExecutorActivate(true)
    .buildProcessEngine();
```

Nevertheless, in karaf console when I deploy the bundle I got the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.datasource.DataSourceException: Error setting driver on UnpooledDataSource. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.initializeDriver(UnpooledDataSource.java:179)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:349)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:55)
```

.......

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.initializeDriver(UnpooledDataSource.java:173)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you print the built MANIFEST ?
And the result of bundle:headers 
I guess your bundle try to import h2 Driver because you did not set it to private.

Quick fix, in karaf, run
`bundle:install mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.4.199`